# Mass conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

My goal: I am trying to create an automated schedule using conditional formatting that, once a block of time has been assigned, will color code itself. The best and the only way I could figure how to do this is best explained in the screenshot below. 2 conditional formatting formulas so that if either "D" or "P" is input, it will block off a different amount of time.

My problem: I am trying to do this in such a way that I don't have to set conditional formatting for 500+ lines of hours in a week.

Solutions I have tried:

- Copy/paste & Format Painter: I have not been able to figure out a combination of absolute references that will allow me to copy and paste my formatting in such a way that it will work given the parameters above.
- Macros (1): My first pass with macros was a suggestion from this board, ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/350378/excel-2007-conditional-formatting-so-that-each-row-shows-low-values-yellow-hig)). Which, once again, I could not figure out how best to utilize it given that absolute references won't work. Seems to just be copying and pasting for me.
- Macros (2): I tried to record myself setting the conditional formatting and using that as a macro, but it will only record the absolute position of the cell that I am applying it to, and I don't know how, if possible, to make it so that the target of the conditional formula shifts downward.

P.S. I'm also looking at possibly using some free appointment scheduling software if I can find one that works for my needs.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your condition to `$B$3:$J$500` and use the following conditional formula for "D":

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B3,"D")
```

For "P", you will need to apply a condition to `$B$3:$J$3`:

```
=B3="P"
```

And apply the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B4,"P")
```

to `$B$4:$J$500`

Comment: OMG okay. You are amazing and you have me 90% of the way there, but maybe I'm just misinterpreting your instructions as I am getting some strange behavior. 
the solution for D is working flawlesly so for that, I already want to bu you a beer. 
For P, it's somehow formatting lines above where I want them to, shading B27 when it should start on B28, and I think that has to do with your 2nd instruction. This is where I am at right now.
edit: gah, I dont know how to add a screen shot. I will add it to the original post.

Comment: NOPE nevermind. I found my mistake.THANK YOU SO MUCH. You are a wizard and if somehow I ever get the opportunity. I will gladly buy you a drink. Cheers!